# subsonic 3 query syntax

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic-active-record

Anyone know of a website that shows various Subsonic 3 query types? I used to use various SS 2 sites that would go through examples of how to get varying types of data. However, am now using SS 3 and am new to .net 3.5 so while the SS site does provide three or four example queries it doesn't explain how they work and there aren't enough of them.

Any suggested sites for learning more SS 3 queries?

Answer (score 1):

Please head to official SubSonic docs page [here](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page). It is evolving yet but has nice stuff just like SubSonic :)

I <3 SubSonic!

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. However, the SS site itself really doesn't provide any info for someone like me who is unfamiliar with the syntax SS3 is using in it's queries (Active Record), I just need some example queries for things like updating, deleting.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to download the source code and look at the Test project as it has a lot more examples than the web site does.  The Unit tests should probably be posted as examples to the site.